# Installing grub on a usb flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, grub

I have installed linux on a usb flash drive. I have also installed grub on it to be able to boot it. However, I am having trouble setting menu.lst file correctly to boot it. This setup:

```
title  Arch Linux
root   (hd0,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda1 ro
initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
```

loaded my current system, rather than the system on my usb flash drive. I have also tried this;

```
title  Arch Linux
root   (hd1,0)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sdb1 ro
initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
```

which loaded initramfs (edit: I am not sure if it was initrd from my harddrive, or from my usb flash drive), but couldn't find and load root partition. Here is my current disk layout

```
rootfs         15672636  6811912  8074396   46% /
/dev             638384        0   638384    0% /dev
run              639768      300   639468    1% /run
/dev/sda1      15672636  6811912  8074396   46% /
shm              639768      216   639552    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda4      50863856 23957848 26906008   48% /home
/dev/sda2      10482364  7557180  2925184   73% /var
/dev/sdb1       7850524   828168  6628580   12% /media/0637815e-9864-4a45-a361-d6c36b3cd3d1
```

`/dev/sdb1` is my usb drive's partition where my linux resides. If it is important, here is my /boot/grub/device.map file

```
(fd0)     /dev/fd0
(hd0)    /dev/sda
(hd1)    /dev/sdb
```

I want to set this up so that usb drive doesn't depend in any way to my current system. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed GRUB on your flash drive, you had to input several commands:

```
sudo grub
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sdb
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
grub> quit
```

The line

```
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sdb
```

where `/dev/sdb` is your flashdrive, should probably help. But you can't issue this command without issuing all the others. So just redo all your setup with the help of these commands.

Comment: I actually just used `grub-install /dev/sdb` when I chrooted into flash drive. My flash drive is (hd1,0) when I chroot into it, but I am not sure what to put into menu.lst file.

Comment: Well, try to do this by hand with `sudo grub` etc., cause the use case (USB flash drive) is not really typical for grub. And in menu.lst try to use `(hd0,0)`.